# My sql query taking time in 700 million rows table with limit also

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, amazon-rds, digital-ocean

> Hello team,
>
> I am facing issue related to fetch data from a table of 700 million
> rows with limit also. Below is the complete detail of our scenario:-
>
> I am having a table with 700 million rows here is table structure:-

```
   CREATE TABLE `product_items` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `model_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `engine_size` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `position` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `vehicle_attributes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `application_notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD INDEX(`product_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD INDEX(`item_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD INDEX(`value`); 
ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD INDEX(`model_id`); 
ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD INDEX(`engine_size`); 


ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

[image]

> Related to this data  Product_id =2 model_id = 1615 item_id =1  total
> 2 results are there.
>
> when i run this query It give results in .5 secs as per screenshot:

```
SELECT `product_items`.* FROM (`product_items`)  WHERE `product_items`.`status` =  '1' AND `product_items`.`item_id` =  1
AND `product_items`.`product_id` =  '2' AND `product_items`.`model_id` =  '1615'  limit 2;
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

> But when i run this query :-

```
 SELECT `product_items`.* FROM (`product_items`)  WHERE `product_items`.`status` =  '1' AND `product_items`.`item_id` =  1
    AND `product_items`.`product_id` =  '2' AND `product_items`.`model_id` =  '1615'  limit 10;
```

[image]

> It take takes too much time and do not  show results after 20 minutes.
>
> We are using digital-ocean database service with  6 CPU + 16 GB + 270 GB Disk

> If anyone can help us in this case will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share code not images

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAN PLAN for your queries

Comment: Hmm..a limit without an order by is going to result in 2 'random' records and the optimizer can't https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: btw The text versions of the 2 queries look the same to me.

Comment: @NickW i have explained in detail with queries and there results. i want faster result for second query.

Comment: @P.Salmon i have updated the last query please check.

Comment: With limit 2 you have been lucky since 2 records are found on the first 1000 records, but in limit 10 it could be that the other 8 records are in the bottom of the list !

Comment: @SelVazi we have only 2 records this is the reason i want to figure it out.

Comment: The EXPLAIN PLAN shows how your DBMS is executing your query e.g. what indexes it's using etc. Without knowing how your query is being executed it is difficult/impossible to recommend changes that may improve the performance of your query

Comment: What indexes???

Comment: @NickW - `EXPLAIN` shows how it is _currently_ working, but gives no clue of what `INDEX` would make it run faster.

Comment: @RickJames correct. Without knowing what indexes it is currently using it is difficult to make any recommendations- there’s no point recommending an index on column A if there is already an index on that column and the query is using it

Comment: @NickW please check i have updated indexes queries in the question.

Comment: @Rickjames please check i have updated indexes queries in the question.

Comment: @SelVazi's one index will help both of the `SELECTs` that you provided.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some indexes, one of them is this one :

```
ALTER TABLE `product_items` ADD INDEX `product_items_index` (status, item_id, product_id, model_id)
```

Also add primary key constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE product_items ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

[for more info check here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: What assumes `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: This solution does not work.